# Strange Error when using FancyBox and jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm getting an error when trying to use Fancybox

Firebug tells me

> jQuery is not defined
>    f.length;a;)this.addEventListener(f[--...s.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})})(jQuery);

I'm positive that all the paths to script and style files are correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Enlarge").fancybox({
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'easingIn'      : 'easeOutBack',
    'easingOut'     : 'easeInBack'
});});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery line should be before the plugin line. That's why it says it's undefined, as it uses the jQuery library in its source.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js">
```

Comment: Thanks that brought up a new error 

c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || b] is not a function
[Break On This Error] this.options.show)for(var k in this.op...end(c.fx,{tick:function(){for(var a=