# Strange New Error when using FancyBox and jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange Error when using FancyBox and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540673/strange-error-when-using-fancybox-and-jquery)

I'm getting an error when trying to use Fancybox

Firebug tells me

```
c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || b] is not a function [Break On This Error] this.options.show)for(var k in this.op...end(c.fx,    {tick:function(){for(var a= –
```

I'm positive that all the paths to script and style files are correct.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Enlarge").fancybox({
'titleShow'     : false,
'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'easingIn'      : 'easeOutBack',
'easingOut'     : 'easeInBack'
});});
 </script>
```

Comment: You should have appended this to your original question and not have created a second one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540673/strange-error-when-using-fancybox-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery easing pack if you want to use other than swing and linear easing options.